# VHDL error in synthesis created by a while loop

Tags: vhdl

Can anyone explain me why this code generates error in synthesis?

```
function funct(x : std_logic_vector) return integer is
    variable counter : integer := x'length - 1;
begin
    while (counter > 0) loop
        if (x(counter) = '1') then
            return counter;
        else
            counter := counter - 1; 
        end if;
    end loop;
    return 0;
end function;
```

this function gives me this error

```
[Synth 8-3380] loop condition does not converge after 2000 iterations
```

But the counter should start from the size of the std_logic_vector (8 or 16).

It doesn't work even if i cap the size of the counter

```
function funct(x : std_logic_vector) return integer is
    variable counter : integer := 7;
begin
    while (counter > 0) loop
        if (x(counter) = '1') then
            return counter;
        else
            counter := counter - 1; 
        end if;
    end loop;
    return 0;
end function;
```

Comment: This may depend on the synth tool : there is a path round the While loop where count is not decremented, and that may confuse synthesis (even though it should return). I would rewrite so there is no such path and try again. In fact I would deprecate the While loop in favour of a FOR loop which is necessarily bounded.

Comment: I changed the while loop into a for loop as you said and solved the problem, thank you

Comment: Historically while loops were not synthesis eligible (IEEE Std 1076.6.-2004 IEEE Standard for VHDL Register Transfer Level (RTL) Synthesis - withdrawn 2012). There is no industry consensus as to rules for determining while loop synthesis eligibility. For loops require a static range for a loop parameter. Functions are expressions, at best fragments of statements or declarations. Here the index range and direction isn't observable, there's no observable determination `counter` falls within `x`s constraints.

Comment: For a synthesis tool that will support while loops you can [constraint the subtype of counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggvkd.jpg). A subtype indication without a constraint will take the value range of the type declaration.